# Countable linear combinations of indicator functions has a canonical form and form a vector space

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory, characteristic-functions

Generalizing simple functions, let us say we have countable linear combinations of indicator functions over $\mathbb{R}^n$, that is $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i\chi_{E_i}(x)$, where $\{E_i\}$ is a set of countable measurable sets and $a_i$ are scalars.

Then, will such functions have a canonical form, like the simple functions, that is, can they be represented as $f(x)=\sum_ib_i\chi_{G_i}(x)$ for constants $b_i$ and pairwise disjoint measurable sets $G_i$. Also, do these functions form a vector space over $\mathbb{R}^n$. The problem seems quite immediate, but I think the real problem here is convergence, as the summands are infinite. Any hints? How to proceed? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Do you require that the canonical form only uses countably many $G_i$? I fear they may not be enough, since all possible intersections of countably many sets are uncountable

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando not necessary that the disjoint sets be countable

Comment: Well, the obvious solution (given a well-defined notion of transfinite summation) is to take the $G_i$ as all the singleton sets of $\mathbb{R}$. $f(x)=\sum_{x_i\in\mathbb{R}}f(x_i)\chi_{\{x_i\}}(x)$

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando thanks, is it usable to prove the vector space property also?

Comment: Well, them being a vector space doesn't require the canonical form - it's easy to see that the sum of two sums of countably many simple functions is itself a sum of countably many simple functions. The other vector space properties shouldn't pose a challenge, and shouldn't require the canonical form either...

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando can we use an enumeration of the values of $f$ here?

Comment: I don't know enough about transfinite summation to answer that, other than I don't think it's necessary...

Comment: @RiccardoOrlando, your representation is too big: the power set ${\Bbb R}^I$ (*all* the functions form $I$ to ${\Bbb R}$).

Answer (score 1):

The set isn't well defined. Take $\bigcap E_i\ne\emptyset$, $a_i = 1$ for all $i$.

Comment: how come in the finite case, the situation is averted?

Comment: @vidyarthi, because all the summations are finite.